# Visual Studio returning Error MSB6006 CL.exe exit with code 1

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, cl.exe

I have tried to build code for testing coverage using the visual Studio 2013 Express version.
But getting an error while compiling the code.
Microsoft.cppcommon.targets(341,5): error MSB6006: "CL.exe" exited with code 1.
Tried to re-install VS and tried many ways but failed. Still, the issue persists.
Kindly help to resolve this issue.

Comment: Why are you using VS 2013 Express instead of VS 2019 Community?

Comment: I am plugin the CTC++ tool with Visual Studio 2013 Express version for checking Code Coverage. 2013 Express version have any disadvantage over the 2019 Community version? Why this error came?

Comment: 2019 version will have many added features and bugs fixed.

Comment: Kindly direct me why the error came?